# finding DB connections that are not closed properly

Tags: java, sql, database, connection

There have been some leaks found in the code of a large project where DB connections are opened yet not closed.
The DB is DB2 and the connections are opened in a java program and not properly closed in a try catch, finally..

Is there any way to search in java for all methods which open a connection yet don't close it?
I'm trying to avoid manually looking through each method that opens a connection to see if it's closed properly.

any help with this tedious task would be cool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net) and [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net) (open-source static code checkers) support detecting unclosed DB connections. They could be integrated into your build process and / or IDE.

PMD, in particular, can be noisy by default, but it can be tuned down using a [custom ruleset](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.3/howtomakearuleset.html) or via [other means](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.3/suppressing.html).

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to my mind is implementing a tool utilizing abstract syntax trees (e.g. as an eclipse plugin). You could write a tool that goes through your methods, checks the nodes for connection initialization commands, and also checks for closing commands.
See:
 - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree see:
 - http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-JavaCodeManipulation_AST/index.html

Otherwise, I think also some kind of custom parser could be used that checks there is an equivalent .close() statement within the same level as the equivalent database open statement.
You would have to check how many levels in you are (utilizing "{" and "}" characters.

See: [Write a custom syntax interpreter in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537283/write-a-custom-syntax-interpreter-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

In relation to your question you could also implement a class with methods that ensure you to close connections. Under I have posted an example.

```
public class Cleaner {

private String dbName = "";
private Connection connection;

public static void CloseResSet(ResultSet res) {
    try {
        if (res != null) {
            res.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        writeMessage(e, "CloseResSet()");
    }
}

public static void closeStatement(Statement stm) {
    try {
        if (stm != null) {
            stm.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        writeMessage(e, "closeStatement()");
    }
}

public static void closeConnection(Connection connection) {
    try {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        writeMessage(e, "closeConnection()");
    }
}

public static void rollBack(Connection connection) {
    try {
        if (connection != null && !connection.getAutoCommit()) {
            connection.rollback();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        writeMessage(e, "rollBack()");
    }
}

public static void setAutoCommit(Connection connection) {
    try {
        if (connection != null && !connection.getAutoCommit()) {
            connection.setAutoCommit(true);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        writeMessage(e, "setAutoCommit()");
    }
}

public static void writeMessage(Exception e, String message) {
    System.err.println("*** Error: " + message + ". ***");
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}

private void OpenConnection() {
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbName);
        System.out.println("Databaseconnection established");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Cleaner.writeMessage(e, "Constructor");
        Cleaner.closeConnection(connection);
    }
}

private void closeConnection() {
    System.out.println("Closes databaseconnection");
    Cleaner.closeConnection(connection);
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks!
we have such a class, but no use if no one calls the methods :s